# Combining a datastore with Mapkit

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, mapkit

Does anyone have any advice on using a datastore with mapkit to provide a database of locations (Restaurants) that are query-able by location?

I would like to use Core data but importing the information into it seems like a project in itself. If anyone has good advice on converting an existing sqlite/cvs file to a coredata sqlite file that would be appreciated.

Is old-fashioned sqlite better than using core data for the task, or is it a case that I should create a web service for the job?

I would like to be able to query the locations based on the map zoom also.

Thanks if you have any advice on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you write your object model correctly, you can just point it at an existing sqLite database and it will read it as if core data generated it in the first place.</strike>

For example, suppose you have an existing sqlite db of people with columns like firstName, lastName, phone# etc. You just create a core data model with a entity with attributes of firstName, lastName, phone# etc. Spell them the same and make sure they have the right type and then point the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` at the existing database. It will read it in fine.

Core data is always the way to go for any larger data management task. It makes everything so much easier once you learn it.

---

Edit01:

Never mind the above. I was thinking of Enterprise Objects. Core data won't easily import most existing SQL.

Instead, I would export the sqlite to csv and then use something like [cCSVParse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546007/convert-excel-document-xls-to-a-plist/1851387#1851387) to convert to plist. Then you can read it in easily to an array or dictionary and use that to populate the core data db.

That will work easily for db's that don't depend on complex relationships. I think the future benefits of having core data will eventually easily pay for the few man hours spent converting.

Comment: Thanks TechZen. I've tried doing that but I'm pretty sure that Core Data doesn't recognise it because the existing sqlite db doesn't have the Core Data generated tables and is not prefixed by an uppercase Z. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks TechZen for answering. Have you done this yourself? I've yet to find a working example of this on the net. 
Seems crazy to have to go from Sqlite -> CSV -> Plist -> Array -> Core Data. How do Apple expect people to load data into programs I wonder?

Comment: You could use existing dbs in the Enterprise Objects which is what Core Data evolved from. I think they so optimized CD for speed that it  can longer efficiently use generic databases. It's focused on data generated by the app. Your right that it is rather glaring weakness.