# How to create a plist file from XL sheet in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, plist

I have data contents are in the XL sheet and now i want to create the plist file depends on the XL sheet. If i have to enter the data manually in the plist from XL sheet, it would take 2 or 3 days, Bcoz XL sheet contains large amount of data. So is any possible to create a plist file from XL sheet without manual?.Is any of the application software available or can i create only as manual? please give me some valuable ideas for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert this [xls to csv](http://www.google.com/search?q=xls+to+csv+converter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) format and than look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546007/convert-excel-document-xls-to-a-plist)